# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot determine the graph element type because the document class is null.

Tags: java, android, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

Hello I'm creating a widget for Samsung Gear. Im using Tizen IDE for wearable. I followed their youtube tutoria: How to Create a Basic Integrated Gear Application.

I tried Build Project in Tizen IDE and there was a build error:

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Web Widget Builder' on project 'SimpleSAPConsumer'.
Build Error : 
Cannot determine the graph element type because the document class is null. Probably this is a projection, use the EXPAND() function
Build Error : 
Cannot determine the graph element type because the document class is null. Probably this is a projection, use the EXPAND() function

Then Error Log said:

```js
eclipse.buildId=
java.version=1.7.0_67
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

Error
Fri May 29 17:01:28 SGT 2015
Build Error :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot determine the graph element type because the document class is null. Probably this is a projection, use the EXPAND() function
 at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientElementIterator.next(OrientElementIterator.java:49)
 at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientElementIterator.next(OrientElementIterator.java:13)
 at org.tizen.common.builder.dependency.DependencyInDB.getVertexFromDB(DependencyInDB.java:236)
 at org.tizen.common.builder.dependency.DependencyInDB.containsVertex(DependencyInDB.java:254)
 at org.tizen.common.builder.BuildProcess.removeResource(BuildProcess.java:413)
 at org.tizen.common.builder.BuildProcess.build(BuildProcess.java:282)
 at org.tizen.web.project.builder.WebBuilder.build(WebBuilder.java:252)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a small spelling mistake or something somewhere because my guess is that there is no 'document' class since it probably doesn't exist in memory or you're referencing a class (Foo dingDong = new Foo(); foo.getStats()) that does not exist in memory.

Comment: Yes, there isn't any document class. Okay, I will try that. Thank you very much! :)